# Delphi ActiveX MSTSCLib

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to play around with some Delphi ActiveX library for MS-RDP (mstscax.dll), so I imported the library into my project, and started looking for some codes snippets on the web. On a first look, it's pretty obvious, but the lack of examples makes it a little complex.

First the library gives an error on Delphi Seattle, on this line:

```
property ConnectWithEndpoint: POleVariant1 write Set_ConnectWithEndpoint;
```

Ok, I commented this line out (not the best solution, I know), but it compiled. Later I tried to change POleVariant1 to OleVariant only, and still compiling.
Ok, after compiled, I tried this code:

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  RDP: TMsRdpClient8NotSafeForScripting;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RDP:= TMsRdpClient8NotSafeForScripting.Create(Nil);
  RDP.Server:= 'xxxx';
  RDP.AdvancedSettings8.RDPPort:= 3389;
  RDP.UserName:= 'terminal';
  RDP.AdvancedSettings8.ClearTextPassword:= '123456';
  RDP.Connect;
  if RDP.Connected.ToBoolean = true then
    ShowMessage('connected')
  else
    ShowMessage('error');

end;
```

I tried some different types for the var RDP, like TMsRdpClient8 only, but still the same problem:
It don't even **try** to connect! While looking on the sniffer, no tcp connections are made, just nothing happens and the "error" message appears. Any idea about how to work with this guy?

Comment: Just drop the TMsRDPClient9 component on your form and set its properties (designtime or runtime). call connect and it connects to the server. Tested here on seatlle and works perfectly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question intrigued me so I tried to import that ActiveX control and try it myself. It seems to work for me, so I'll explain what I did.

I imported the mstscax.dll ActiveX control then added it to a new package in order to install components onto the tool palette. I immediately ran into the error you did with the ConnectWithEndpoint property. I changed the type in the declaration to OleVariant because the Set_ConnectWithEnpoint property setter function takes an OleVariant. There is clearly something about the type information that our ActiveX importer code is getting confused by. Either way, that change got the file to compile and install the component package. There are now a bunch of TMsRdpClientXXXX components.

Created a new VCL Forms project, then dropped the TMsRdpClient9 component into the form. Added a TButton and then added this code into the button's OnClick handler:

```
  MsRdpClient91.Server := '<some remote server>';
  MsRdpClient91.Domain := 'embarcadero.com';
  MsRdpClient91.UserName := 'abauer';
  MsRdpClient91.Connect;
```

Once I ran the app, and pressed the button, it connected and the content of the ActiveX control showed the remote server login screen just fine.

I'm running Windows 10, build 10565.

Here's what I'm seeing on my little app I wrote:
[image]

Comment: Came to the same conclusion, any reason for the erroneous POleVariant1 variable on the ConnectWithEndpoint property? Is this a bug in the TLB file or a misinterpretation on the Delphi side?

Comment: Don't know... Haven't looked at the TLB imported code yet. I've seen a lot of instances where the TLB information is ambiguous and can throw off many TLB importers. It is odd that this is a write-only property, so that may have some bearing on this.

Comment: Hi, as I said on the question, I'm "playing" with this, specially to understand how to use/install ActiveX components. Do you guys have any tutorial on how to install that? I just go to Components > Import Component > ActiveX Control > Select Control > Create Unit or Add Unit to the project... This doesn't give me any TMsRdpClient9 component to be added on my VCL forms...

Comment: Hi user3810691, you must import the control into a new package and install it, like Allen said...

Comment: On the last page of the Import Component wizard, select Install to Existing Package or Install to New Package. I used New Package and named it MsRdp. It will fail to compile in the next step because of the error on ConnectWithEndpoint property. Fix that then right-click on the package project and select Install. This should build and install package as a design/runtime package. You may need to update the search paths to point to the imported unit... I'm running an internal developer build of the product, so I'm not sure you'll need to do that.

Comment: I tried this you told me but I get the error when tryin to run the app: `Cannot run project unless a host application is defined. Use Run|Parameters dialog`... What I did before was creating a new unit, and importing the unit to my current project... But then you guys said about the component on the VCL, so I stated that I'm doing it wrong...

Comment: You're trying to "run" the package project. Once the package is installed (you should save the source as well), create a new VCL application project. Then you can "drop" the component onto the form.

Comment: Yeah got it.. Let me test, thank you! Be right back to accept answer.

Comment: I did that and I'm receiving AV errors yet. Can you share in some website the TLB .pas file. Thx.