# Imported ActiveX Control in Delphi 10.2 CE Unavailable In Palette

Tags: delphi, com, activex

I am using the community edition but am not aware of any limits in this regard.

I have imported `mstscax.dll` via `Component |> Import Component...` and selecting "ActiveX." The component does not show up in in the component palette and editing the the DFM directly to include a TMsRdpClient[digit] component results in form builder errors stating the component can not be found.

However it is possible to get a premade project (RDPWrap's [RDPCheck](https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap/tree/master/src-rdpcheck)) to build and run if those errors are "Cancelled" instead of "Ignored." It is also necessary to resolve the error [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33554439/delphi-activex-mstsclib).

In a project I have created myself I am able to add the generated file `MSTSCLib_TLB` to the uses clause and to add a variable of type `TMsRdpClient7` to a form. In the `FormCreate` function (for example) I am able to call `TMsRdpClient7.Create(Self)` and then access the properties of the object. If I set enough properties (see below) I get the authorization popup and see the login screen after calling `TMsRdpClient7.Connect`.

```
  with RDP do
  begin
    Left := 0;
    Top := 0;
    Width := Self.Width;
    Height := Self.Height;
    Parent := Self;
    Visible := True;

    DisconnectedText := 'Disconnected.';
    UserName := '';
    Server := '127.0.0.2';
  end;
```

Comment: When you imported the ActiveX, did you check *Generate component wrappers* and assign it a palette page?

Comment: @KenWhite: If I hadn't I believe `MSTSCLib_TLB.pas` would not have been generated. I tried to have the components placed in the ActiveX page (which does not show up by default) and some other page which is already populated. It did not appear either time.

Comment: No. You can import an ActiveX control without creating components for the palette. (If that wasn't the case, there would not be a checkbox to check to indicate you want to do so, would there?) I have dozens of _TLB.pas files on my machine that have no components on the VCL palette. A TLB file does not require any component code to be generated at all.

Comment: The only checkbox I see looked like it determined whether the type header `.pas` file was generated. I ticked anything that looked relevant and selected the component tab. See accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing MSTScax.Dll works fine for me on Delphi 10.2.3 and results in 25 components being displayed on the `ActiveX` tab of the component palette, starting with the `TMsTScaxNotSafeForScripting` component.

I could post the exact steps used but I'm wondering whether you are simply missing a step:

After you've corrected the `ConnectWithEndpoint` Property type to `OleVariant` and compiled the package which contains your import unit `MSTSCLib_TLB.Pas`, let's call it RDP.Pkg, you need to go to the `Project Manager`, right-click on `RDP.Bpl` and click `Install` - then, it should show up on the `ActiveX` tab.  Does that work for you?

Btw, I'm starting Delphi in the ordinary way from its deskstop link on Win10 64-bit, not using special measures such 'Run as Administrator'.

Comment: What made the difference was selecting `Install to New Package` and creating the package to get a `.bpl`. Otherwise the palette page selection is shown but the component never shows up.